# Автозаполнение формы

Tags: python, django

Как сделать заполнение формы по существующим данным для изменения? Если можно, небольшой кусочек кода.

Answer (score 2):

Немного непонятен вопрос. Имеется ввиду заполнить начальными данными, взятыми откуда-то?
Тогда так:

```
def smth(request):

    # Ключи словаря соответствуют именам полей заполняемой формы    
    initial_data = {'name': 'Ivan', 'surname': 'Ivanov', email: 'ivanov@mail.ru'}  
    some_form = SomeForm(initial=initial_data)
```

Или имеется ввиду что-то другое?

Comment: по этому вопросу разобрался. Спасибо!